# How To Validate Image Height And Width Magento Admin Form Upload Field

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload, file-upload, prototype-js

I want To validate Image Height And Width on Submit in Magento Admin Back-end.
I want to upload & different Sizes Of Images by magento admin...So For That I want to validate image Height and Width In magento admin form upload field...

```
$fieldset->addField('image_1', 'file', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('frontlayout')->__('Layout Image'),
            'required' => true,
            'name' => 'image_1',
            'class' => 'required-entry',
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to validate the image uploaded for the catalog<

```
public function validateUploadFile($filePath) {

    $testsize[] = getimagesize($filePath);
    if (!(getimagesize($filePath)) || ($testsize[0][0] < 900) || ($testsize[0][1] < 900)) {
        Mage::throwException($this->__('Image size must be same or greater than 900px * 900px .'));
    }

    $_processor = new Varien_Image($filePath);
    return $_processor->getMimeType() !== null;
}
```

Comment: solution needed in prototype   not in php